AWS API GATEWAY giving 500 response for GET calls after extension as S3 Proxy
I'm playing around with AWS API Gateway dynamoDB and now (newly) S3.
Before my API Gateway was used to provide Get and Post methods for some resources which where linked to a dynamoDB table. Worked fine so far.
Then I implemented S3 Proxy to the API Gateway followed basically this guideline: https://medium.com/@vaishnavipolichetti/uploading-files-to-s3-using-api-gateway-558769ec5a03
and here is my resource-tree of the API:

the /cars and cars/{id} are linked to an dynamoDB table while /cars/documents shall be the endpoint to S3 file storage.
After following the mentioned guideline I recognized that /cars/documents is working as expected however little later when I used the /cars GET method I got an 500 response.
When I use the test function within the AWS web interface it works fine. Only using the GET method from "external" like postman / myApp / rested / safari all is giving me 500 response.
Does anyone has a clue how to further debug? As I got no information where the problem could be?
One major thing which could have an impact was that the guideline tells to change API-Settings for binary media types as "/"
Anticipating that this might be a problem I already extended my GET calls with a Content-Type=application/json and Accept=application/json. However this doesn't worked.
Edit: Meanwhile in Cloudwatch I found this error:

Execution failed due to configuration error: Unable to transform
request

Edit2:
So the root cause is definitely the wildcard/wildcard for binary media types. Obviously this is disturbing the whole api. When I remove it and place for example "application/pdf" then all works fine. However I'd like to have some setup which would threat everyrhing as binary which is not "application/json" does anyone know how to deal with? Currently I need to specify each and every binary file type (like pdf, xls, doc, png vice versa) in order to not have a conflict with "application/json" which is the major protocol for dynamoDB entities.
